# Can I create definition file for local JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a `a.js` file that contains:

```
export function a() {}
```

and I want it to import it from the file `b.ts` (in the same directory) like that:

```
import { a } from './a.js'
```

How can I tell TypeScript what the file a.js contains so that compilation of this import succeeds?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: @blorkfish b.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module './a.js'.

Comment: I think you will need to check the module resolution documentation.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is needed for this to work is typescript definition file named same as JavaScript file (`a.d.ts` in this case) that contains:

```
export function a();
```

It can also specify parameter types, additional exported functions and classes and must use `export` keyword to indicate what the JavaScript file actually exposes.

One other change is that this JavaScript module needs to be then imported in `b.ts` as:

```
import { a } from './a' // without .js
```

so it takes typescript definition file into account. It will still use implementation from `a.js` file. It works with webpack too.

---

If you don't want to describe what's inside `a.js` and have TypeScript just accept it you can create `a.d.ts` file like that:

```
declare var whateva:any;
export = whateva;
```

Then you can import it like this:

```
import * as ajs from './a'
```

and then refer to any function exposed by `a.js` in your TypeScript files like that:

```
ajs.a();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use a statement:

```
declare var a:any;
```

(after the import) in this same file you are using the `a` (i this case in `b.ts`). Thanks to this the TS compiler will not complain. Also your IDE will not shown the errors.

Comment: Doesn't work. TypeScript compiler still complains about missing module. I'm using version 2.0.2 of TypeScript compiler.